# stackoverflow exception while decrypting string with bouncy castle in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, bouncycastle, licenses.licx

Recently a new project is assigned to me and its developed in ages old VB.net technology. Initially it was not even building  with some error in **licenses.licx** file. I have removed all content from licenses.licx, the project is now building and i can debug and test most of the part, but the code exits with stack overflow exception while decrypting a string.
this line

```
Dim userName As String = clsCrypto.Decrypt("encryptedstringUserName==")
Dim Password As String = clsCrypto.Decrypt("encryptedstringPassword==")
```

I have searched a lot but still unable to figure out how clsCrypto is working and why its throwing stackoverflow exception. Also i am unable to find any certificate or other encryption decryption key.  A help or point to correct direction will definitely make my day.

PS. The developer has already left and no one has any idea about how this thing is working.

[image]

Comment: Are you able to view the stack trace from the exception to see what's referencing itself recursively?

Comment: "Exception of type system.stackoverflowException is thrown" . nothing else. I have also updated question

Comment: Which Bouncy Castle are you using? The legacy one (https://www.nuget.org/packages/BouncyCastle) or the new one (https://www.nuget.org/packages/BouncyCastle.Cryptography/)? Might be worth to swap out one for the other and try it.

Comment: using legacy one. Tried to switch to bouncycastle.cryptography but clsCrypto is not available in it

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73817567/bouncy-castle-encrypt-and-decrypt-password-org-bouncycastle-crypto-invalidciph

Comment: Are you sure clsCrypto isn't a defined instance of some bouncycastle object type?  If you right click on it and got to View Declaration, what happens?